# obtener datos de una lista en un modal bootstrap hacia un formulario (cambiando de window.open a modales)

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-3

estoy cambiando los `window.open` en una pagina por modales de bootstrap pero me he topado con un error y espero me pueda explicar correctamente y me puedan ayudar:

Antes usaba la siguiente función para abrir una ventana emergente con la pagina `ventana.php`:

```
    function abreVentana(){
    miPopup = window.open("ventana.php","miwin","width=700,height=380,scrollbars=yes");
    miPopup.focus();
    });
    }
```

Y usaba la siguiente función para enviar los datos al formulario `form_busqueda` de la pagina padre `index`:

```
   function pon_prefijo(pref,nombre) {
    console.dir(parent.opener.document);
  parent.opener.document.form_busqueda.cod.value=pref;
  parent.opener.document.form_busqueda.nombre.value=nombre;
  parent.window.close();
  parent.opener.validarcliente();
  }
```

Ahora uso esta funcion para abrir la pagina `ventana.php` en un modal sin embargo no se como hacer una función equivalente al la funcion `pon_prefijo(pref,nombre)` que usaba con `window.open`:

```
  function abreVentana(){
           $('.modal-body').load('ventana.php',function(){
           $('#Modalvclientes').modal({show:true});
           });
           }
```

He probado varias opciones expuestas en varios foros y blogs pero ninguna me ha funcionado.

edit:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Modalvclientes" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Clientes</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>    
    <form id="form_busqueda"  name="form_busqueda" method="post" action="rejilla.php?serie=<?php echo $serie; ?>" target="frame_rejilla">
                        <table class="fuente8" width="98%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:16%;">Codigo de cliente </td>
                                <td style="width:68%;">
                                    <input id="codcliente" type="text" class="cajaPequena" name="codcliente" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $codcliente ?>" /> 
                                    <img src="../img/ver.png" style="width: 16px;height:16px;" onclick="abreVentana()" title="Buscar cliente" onmouseover="style.cursor=cursor" alt="buscar"/> 
                                    <img src="../img/cliente.png" width="16" height="16" onclick="validarcliente()" title="Validar cliente" onmouseover="style.cursor=cursor" alt="cliente"/></td>
                                <td style="width:5%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="width:5%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <!--<td style="width:6%;text-align:right;">&nbsp;</td>-->
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Nombre</td>
                                <td><input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="cajaGrande" maxlength="45" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>" onblur="buscar()" /></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Num. <?php echo $descripcionmin; ?></td>
                                <td><input id="numdocumento" type="text" class="cajaPequena" name="numdocumento" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $numdocumento ?>" onblur="buscar()"/></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>-->
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Estado</td>
                                <td><select id="cboEstados" name="cboEstados" class="comboMedio" onfocus="buscar()">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Todos los estados</option>
                                        <option value="1">Sin Facturar</option>
                                        <option value="2">Facturados</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Fecha de inicio</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="fechainicio" type="text" class="cajaPequena" name="fechainicio" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $fechainicio ?>" readonly="readonly"  onfocus="buscar()" />
                                    <img src="../img/calendario.png"  id="Image1" style="width:16px;height:16px;border: 0px;"  onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" title="Calendario" alt="fecha" onfocus="buscar()"/>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        Calendar.setup(
                                        {
                                            inputField : "fechainicio",
                                            ifFormat   : "%d/%m/%Y",
                                            button     : "Image1"
                                        }
                                        
                                    );
                                    </script>   </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>-->
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Fecha de fin</td>
                                <td><input id="fechafin" type="text" class="cajaPequena" name="fechafin" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $fechafin ?>" readonly="readonly" onfocus="buscar()" />
                                    <img src="../img/calendario.png" id="Image2" style="width:16px;height:16px;border:0;"  onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" alt="calendario" onfocus="buscar()"/>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        Calendar.setup(
                                        {
                                            inputField : "fechafin",
                                            ifFormat   : "%d/%m/%Y",
                                            button     : "Image2"
                                        }
                                    );
                                    </script></td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>-->
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="hidden" id="iniciopagina" name="iniciopagina" />
                    </form>
```

Comment: PD: soy novato con javascript

Comment: Dentro de la función solo necesitas acceder por ID de los campos para asignar los valores que estás recibiendo por parámetro: `$('#codcliente').val(pref); $('#nombre').val(nombre)`, si falla, es porque seguramente estás repitiendo IDs y éstos deben ser únicos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontré la solución "parcialmente" el problema era que estaba cargando la función con un `<a href="javascript:pon_prefijo(<?php echo $codcliente; ?>,'<?php echo $nombre; ?>')">` lo cambie a un evento `onclick="pon_prefijo('<?php echo $codcliente; ?>','<?php echo $nombre; ?>')"` y ya funciona pero ahora no se como cerrar el modal, no se cierra con `data-dismiss="modal"` ni agregando `$('#Modalvclientes').modal({hide:true});` a la función.

edit:
al final he conseguido cerrar el modal creando una función global en la pagina principal `window.closeModal = function(){$('#Modalvclientes').modal('hide');};`
y llamándola desde el iframe en la función `pon_prefijo()` con `window.parent.closeModal();`

espero le ayude a alguien en un futuro.